# Setting up OpenGL and GLFW on Mac OS X 10.8.2

Tags: macos, opengl, terminal, osx-mountain-lion, glfw

I am having an issue setting up GLFW / OpenGL on Mac. I am running a fully updated Mac OSX 10.8.2, so I am assuming that I have the most up to date mac-compatible OpenGL version and I have compiled the GLFW libraries (2.7.7) using homebrew (OS X package manager).

I am trying to use the following guide, [open.gl](http://open.gl/context#GLFW) , and am using the recommended code snippet to verify OpenGL and GLFW are working properly:

```
\#include <GL/glfw.h>

int main()
{
  glfwInit();
  glfwSleep( 1.0 );
  glfwTerminate();
}
```

This should show a console application and exit after a second.

I am compiling with g++ in terminal and receiving no compile errors:

```
g++ a.cpp -lglfw -framework OpenGL -framework Cocoa -framework IOkit
```

When I run the program with

```
 ./a.out
```

nothing happens, but I do get the 1 second delay before it closes, so I know that much is working.

Let me know if there is any further information that might be helpful.

Comment: You have no GL context or window - just a 'command line' application running on a terminal. See: `glfwOpenWindow`

Comment: This was the answer. Thank you. I cannot post the answer myself, because I am a new member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no GL context or window - just a `command line` application running on a terminal.

Refer to the `glfwOpenWindow` documentation.